# How to plot density plot by label (categorical variable) for each numeric column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have tried to use the mines and rocks data (http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/connectionist+bench+(sonar,+mines+vs.+rocks)) to do EDA. I have put the following code that can plot the density plot for each numeric column.

Is there a way to plot the same chart for each numeric variable in the data set but with two lines in each density plot based on if it is M or R (the last column). Therefore we can see which variable shows different distribution for the label M vs R.

```
import pandas as pd

# import file
file = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning- 
databases/undocumented/connectionist-bench/sonar/sonar.all-data'
mr_df = pd.read_table(file, sep=',', header=None)

mr_df.plot(kind='density', subplots=True, layout=(8,8), sharex=False, legend=False, fontsize=1, figsize=(12,12))
plt.savefig('density plot.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plt.subplots(nrows=8, ncols=8, figsize=(12,12))
for i in range(1, 61):
    plt.subplot(8, 8, i)
    mr_df.loc[mr_df[60] == 'R', i-1].plot(kind='density')
    mr_df.loc[mr_df[60] == 'M', i-1].plot(kind='density')

plt.subplot_tool() # allows easy adjustment of the subplot spacing
```

[image]